# jquery validator creditcardtypes usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jquery.validator plugin to validate the credit card type and the credit card number so they match. For example validate a Visa number and the creditcardtype is Visa.

I just need to know how to pass the credit card type so that the credit card number is for that type of credit card only to pass validation:

Here is my current code

```
$jq('#frmCompleteOrder').validate({

      // Specify the validation rules
      rules: {
          txtCardholderName: {
              required: true,
          },
          txtCardNumber: {
              required: true,
              creditcard: true,
              creditcardtypes: {type:'visa'} <-- how do I pass the credit card type here
          },
          selShippingState: {
              required: true,
              select_one: true
          }
      },

      // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            txtCardholderName: {
              required: "Please enter a value for Card Holder Name",
              minlength: "Card Holder Name must be at least 5 characters long"
          }
      },

      submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.submit();
      }
}); //validate
```

Comment: I think you should update your validator config each time your "credit card type" changes.

Comment: Yeah, the credit card type is dynamic, I just put 'visa' as an example of what I want to pass to the validator param.  I need to know how to pass the cc type as a param.  My example is just pseudo code and needs replacing to the correct format.

Comment: Where did the `select_one: true` and `creditcard: true` rules come from?  They're not part of this plugin.  You cannot make up new rules without first using the `.addMethod()` method.  See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/